# How to setup maildev email persistant storage with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm setup maildev for my project using docker compose.
It is working correct, I able can sent email to maildev however I facing with an issue when setup Directory for persisting mails. I try to setup by the userguide but is not work. Email will be clear  after restart docker.

This is maildev github: https://github.com/maildev/maildev

Maildev docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/maildev/maildev

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file: **mail-directory** seem not working

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  maildev:
    hostname: maildev
    command: bin/maildev --web 80 --smtp 25 --mail-directory /home/maildev/data
    volumes:
      - ./var/data/maildev:/home/maildev/data
    ports:
      - "1080:80"
    networks:
      - my-network
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet possible in the latest Docker release (v1.1.0). This version of MailDev does not support the `--mail-directory` flag and will use a temporary directory of its choice instead.

The contents of this temporary directory is cleared each time MailDev is started so creating a volume for the this directory will not be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

I was able do achieve this with this configuration :

```
mailer:
    image: maildev/maildev    
    volumes:
      - /home/maildev:/home/maildev:rw
    environment:
      - MAILDEV_MAIL_DIRECTORY=/home/maildev
    networks:
      - default
```

The SMTP port will be 1025 and Web access to port 1080.

Hope this will help !